# Sanity.io nextjs (next-sanity) example client

Tags: next.js, sanity

I'm attempting to migrate from sanity v4 which means I'm also upgrading from nextjs 13.4 to next 14, to next-sanity v7. The biggest hurdle seems to be going from v4 to v5, which is why I am attempting to follow this migration guide:

https://github.com/sanity-io/next-sanity/blob/main/MIGRATE-v4-to-v5-app-router.md

However, they are not showing what the client.js-file looks like. Previously, I would simply import client and not use any getClient()-function.

Assuming I'm trying to follow this guide, what would a getClient-function look like that works with this example? (Or perhaps just the entire client.js)

This is what my client.js-file looks like right now:

```
import { createClient } from "next-sanity"
import { apiVersion, dataset, projectId, useCdn } from "../schemas/env"

export const client = createClient({
  projectId,
  apiVersion,
  dataset,
  useCdn,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sanity-client` w/ Next 14 and Sanity 3, this is what my createClient looks like:

```js
import { createClient } from 'next-sanity';

export const sanityClient = createClient({
  dataset: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_DATASET,
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_PROJECT_ID,
  token: process.env.SANITY_STUDIO_API_TOKEN,
  useCdn: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
  apiVersion: '2023-08-01',
  perspective: 'published',
  useCdn: true,
});
```

This is what a query looks like once you get the client set up:

```js
// get an issue in my example, using groq
export async function getIssue() {
  const data = await sanityClient.fetch(
    `*[_type == "custom-type"][0] {
      whatever
    }`,
    {},
    {
      cache: 'no-store', // depends on next caching strategy
      next: {
        // revalidate: 600,
      },
    },
  );

  const metadata = {
    title: `XYZ`, // you would set this dynamically
  };

  return metadata;
}
```